# How to delay the upload progress of Drap & Drop uploader

Tags: file-upload, webforms, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

Let's say, I have a form, with a few input fields and a drag and drop upload area (dropzone.js). My attempt is, in lieu of starting uploading right away after dropping file into the drag and drop area, I want to, like, display the file there, and when I click the submit button of the form, it will be uploaded along with submitting the form information.

Is is possible with drag and drop?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `autoProcessQueue:false` and

```js
$('#upload-button').click(function(){
    myDropzone.processQueue();      
});
```

this will work.